# bootstrap navbar search under navbar-nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put bootstrap navbar search under navbar-nav?

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand brand brand-name navbar-left" href="#">Brand Name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a><span class="current-bar-box"><span class="current-bar"></span></span></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">What's On</a></li>
                <li><a href="article-project.php">Publications</a></li>
                <li><a href="article.html">Multimedia</a></li>
                <li><a href="article.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>

          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Result:

[image]

What I am after:

[image]

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

On mobile devices, for an example:

[image]

Comment: What do you except in mobile devices?

Comment: How would you like to have this show up on mobile devices?

Comment: @Daan please see my edit above.

Comment: @Win please see my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like your search bar will be in the flow of the document (seeing as it's overlaid on top of both the navbar and the slider image), so this is one of those cases where absolute positioning provides the simplest solution.

Since you only want the search field to appear in this position on wider devices, be sure to use a media query around any styles you end up using (I used Bootstrap's tablet breakpoint):

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar{
        position: relative; /* Important if the navbar isn't the default 100% of the screen width */
    }

    .navbar-form.navbar-left{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 100%;
    }
}
```

Appearance using otherwise default Bootstrap CSS:

[image]

And here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/C4HuMlTfJ2) to demonstrate. You may need to adjust the `top` and `right` values as needed by your design. Fortunately, Bootstrap's normal CSS for narrower breakpoints fits almost perfectly with how you want the search field displayed, so you don't need to write any CSS specifically for them.

*(You will have to write a bit more CSS for hiding/replacing the submit button with an inline magnifying glass on narrower widths, but this shouldn't be too tough. Bootstrap has some handy classes for conditionally showing elements at different screen widths, if needed.)*

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.